# Execute PL SQL with Java

Tags: java, plsql

I have the following PL SQL that I am trying to run from my Java application.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
XMLVal  CLOB := '<some xml here>';

Msg Varchar2(100);
BEGIN
  mands.Lib_Interface.LoadData(Msg, XMLVal);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(Msg);
END;
```

My java code is ----EDITED----- updated the prepareCall from

```
CallableStatement vStatement = vDatabaseConnection.prepareCall("begin ? := mands.Lib_Interface.LoadData(?, ?); end;");
```

to

```
CallableStatement vStatement = vDatabaseConnection.prepareCall("begin mands.Lib_Interface.LoadData(?, ?); end;");
```

---

```
Connection vDatabaseConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(dbAddress, dbSchema,dbScemaPassword);
CallableStatement vStatement = vDatabaseConnection.prepareCall("begin mands.Lib_Interface.LoadData(?, ?); end;");

vStatement.setString(3, xml);
vStatement.registerOutParameter( 1, Types.VARCHAR );
vStatement.registerOutParameter( 2, Types.VARCHAR );
vStatement.executeUpdate();
```

However when I run the code i get the following SQLException

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 14:
PLS-00222: no function with name 'LOADDATA' exists in this scope
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
```

I have no issues when using the command with SQL Developer.

I have googled the issue but at a loss. Any help would be appreciated.

Regards

Tone

-----------------------------EDIT-------------------------

So I have also tried

```
vStatement.setClob(3, new StringReader(xml));
vStatement.registerOutParameter( 1, Types.VARCHAR );
vStatement.registerOutParameter( 2, Types.VARCHAR );
vStatement.execute();
```

and

```
Clob clob = vDatabaseConnection.createClob();
clob.setString(1, xml);
vStatement.setClob(3, clob);
vStatement.registerOutParameter( 1, Types.VARCHAR );
vStatement.registerOutParameter( 2, Types.VARCHAR );
```

but am still getting the same error.

-----------------EDIT-----------------------

Here is the working code

```
Connection vDatabaseConnection = DriverManager.getConnection("dbAddress","dbSchema","dbPassword");
CallableStatement vStatement = vDatabaseConnection.prepareCall("begin mands.Lib_Interface.LoadData(?, ?); end;");

vStatement.setClob(2, new StringReader(xml));
vStatement.registerOutParameter( 1, Types.VARCHAR );
vStatement.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/callablestatement-object-example.htm

Comment: it is better that you create a stored procedure and from Java just call it... I am not sure that you can embed the pl/sql anonymous block in java

Comment: @Dazak - I will look into how to do that if that is the preferred method of executing PLSQL

Comment: @OldProgrammer - Thanks for the link. Reading now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the PL/SQL code you are using 2 variables to call a procedure:

- XMLVal, type: CLOB, in-parameter
- Msg, type VARCHAR2, out-parameter

In the JDBC code you are calling the procedure as a function (notice the assignment operator). Hence the error *no **function** with name 'LOADDATA'*:

```
begin ? := mands.Lib_Interface.LoadData(?, ?); end;`
```

You should call it as a procedure with argument 1 being the out-parameter and argument 2 the in-parameter:

```
begin mands.Lib_Interface.LoadData(?, ?); end;
```

Also there are some other minor errors in your code:

In your Java code you are setting a `String` for the CLOB parameter. Try using a `StringReader` with the `setClob`-method to assign the in-parameter. Also, I'm not sure if `vStatement.executeUpdate()` works, try using just `execute`.

```
    Connection vDatabaseConnection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@xx.xxx.xx.xxx:1521:xxx", "user","pass");
    CallableStatement vStatement = vDatabaseConnection.prepareCall("begin mands.Lib_Interface.LoadData(?, ?); end;");

    StringReader reader = new StringReader(xml);
    vStatement.registerOutParameter(1, Types.VARCHAR);
    vStatement.setClob(2, reader);
    vStatement.execute();
    String msg = vStatement.getString(1);
```

Alternatively, you can try the ANSI 92 syntax `{ call schema.package.procedure(?, ?) }`:

```
CallableStatement vStatement = vDatabaseConnection.prepareCall("{call mands.Lib_Interface.LoadData(?, ?) }");

StringReader reader = new StringReader(xml);
vStatement.registerOutParameter(1, Types.VARCHAR);
vStatement.setClob(2, reader);
vStatement.execute();
String msg = vStatement.getString(1);
```

If that's still not working, make sure you are using the same user in JDBC as you are in SQL Developer.

Comment: Thank you. I will give this a go. Will update with results

Comment: so I have tried that and still get the same error.
My new code reads.

    vStatement.setClob(3, new StringReader(xml));
    vStatement.registerOutParameter( 1, Types.VARCHAR );
    vStatement.registerOutParameter( 2, Types.VARCHAR );
    vStatement.execute();

Comment: Did you change the prepareCall argument to `"begin mands.Lib_Interface.LoadData(?, ?); end;"`?

Comment: Are you sure it's the same error? The original `PLS-00222: no function with name 'LOADDATA' exists in this scope` was because you treated it as a function when it is a procedure. Now if you're using @boskoop's version you are treating it correctly as a procedure, so it it's still failing I would expect a different error.

Comment: @William Robertson: Thx for pointing that out, I instinctively changed it in my solution without emphasizing it. This seems to be a essential to the problem.

Comment: Thanks guys will check this first thing in the morning. I had failed to notice the change to the code.
---------
Actually just checked my code and I had made the change.
vDatabaseConnection.prepareCall("begin mands.Lib_Interface.LoadData(?, ?); end");

Will run tomorrow and post the error.

Comment: Not sure what I was doing Friday. This works a treat! Thank you for all your help